# Remove spaces and \n from inside the list python

Tags: list

This is the list I am getting:

['', '', '      NRGD\n    ', '\n    MicroSectors U.S. Big Oil Index -3X Inverse Leveraged ETN\n  ', '    $102.24\n  ', '    5012.00%\n  \n2070.00', '\n  ']

I want to "clean it up" and return:

['NRGD', 'MicroSectors U.S. Big Oil Index -3X Inverse Leveraged ETN', '$102.24', '5012.00%', '2070.00']

I want to basically remove all the items that are just spaces or \n as for the ones with actual text I want to remove the spaces and \n and just have the item with text.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a list comprehension here:

```py
inp = ['', '', ' NRGD\n ', '\n MicroSectors U.S. Big Oil Index -3X Inverse Leveraged ETN\n ', ' $102.24\n ', ' 5012.00%\n \n2070.00', '\n ']
output = [x.strip() for x in inp if x.strip()]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['NRGD', 'MicroSectors U.S. Big Oil Index -3X Inverse Leveraged ETN',
 '$102.24', '5012.00%\n \n2070.00']
```

The above logic says to retain any list element which, after stripping leading and trailing whitespace, is not empty string.  It then retains such elements with whitespace trimmed.